# Python function .HoughCircle() Accuracy

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I would like to know what the accuracy of this function is:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(binary, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=A, minDist=B, minRadius=C, maxRadius=D, param2=E)
```

Currently the centers of the found circles are only resolved to one pixel interval. All found circle centers end at .5. Can the function also resolve to subpixel resolution?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please edit your question with the library that this function is from, and with your code?

Comment: I can only share this line:
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(binary, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=A, minDist=B, minRadius=C, maxRadius=D, param2=E)

I know it isnt much... in vector circle there are the x, y  and radius results and the resolution is just 1px

Comment: "All found circle centers end at .5" please explain what you mean: 0.5 whats? By "found" do you mean the results of HoughCircles? Opencv is open source - have you looked at the source code?

Comment: I am having this same problem, 0.5 only for circle center. For example, houghcircles is providing, 432.5, 674.5 for pixel values. Looking for better accuracy